# Qual a análise morfossintática da frase: "Que bonita pintura e poema!"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxe, morfologia

Não consigo entender a função morfológica e sintática da palavra **que** na frase. Sugeri que fosse realizada a análise morfossintática da frase completa para que fique melhor explicado.

Comment: Nesse caso, *que* tem função de advérbio, como dizem o Houaiss e o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/que). Interessante que *that* tinha essa função no inglês, mas hoje é arcaico.

Comment: Então no caso a função sintática seria adjunto adverbial de intensidade? Ou seria outro tipo?

Comment: Zewill, estás certo. Se quiseres melhor evidência, o Houaiss diz que *como* em «Como cheira bem a sua caldeirada» é advérbio de intensidade e também põe *que* como sinônimo de *como*. Se quiseres checá-lo tu mesmo, eis o link do Houaiss: https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/.

Comment: Ótima resposta @Schilive. Não consigo explorar o link apresentado porque precisa ser usuário.

Comment: Zewill, sim, porém, é “de grátis”.